# Apply transition animation on navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have coded navbar to be sticky on scroll and change color as well. But all of the changes happen so suddenly and I have no idea how to improve that. Here are the code samples:

```js
// jshint esversion: 6
window.onscroll = function() { myFunction(); };

let navbar = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation")[0];
let sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
       navbar.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
       navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
/* ------------------------------------- */
/* BASIC RESET */
/* ------------------------------------- */
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

html { font-size: 62.5%; }

body {
     box-sizing: inherit;
     color: #777;
     background-color: #fff;
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     font-size: 1.8rem;
     font-weight: 400;
     line-height: 1.5;
}

.clearfix {zoom: 1;}
.clearfix:after {
    content: '.';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE REUSABLE CONTENT */
/* ------------------------------------- */

/* HTML contents */

h1, h2.header-heading, h2 {
     margin: 0;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 {
     font-size: 4.5rem;
     color: #fff;
     letter-spacing: .4rem;
     word-spacing: .5rem;
     font-weight: 300;
}

h2 {
     font-size: 3.5rem;
}

/* Links */

a {
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline-block;
}

/* Buttons */

.btn {
     border: 1px solid #fff;
     border-radius: .3rem;
     font-size: 1.6rem;
     padding: 1.2rem 3.5rem;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     color: #fff;
     background-color: transparent;
     font-weight: bold;
     letter-spacing: .3rem;
     transition: all .2s;
}

.btn:hover {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #000;
}

/* Utility classes */

.u-margin-top-small {
     margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.u-text-align-center {
     text-align: center;
}

.u-inline-block {
     display: inline-block;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE HEADER SECTION */
/* ------------------------------------- */

header {
     background-color: #353353;
     height: 98vh;
}

.hero-text-box {
     position: absolute;
     top: 40%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h2.header-heading {
     font-size: 3.5rem;
     margin-top: 2rem;
     color: #F9F871;
     font-weight: 400;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE NAVBAR */
/* ------------------------------------- */

.navigation {
     position: relative;
     padding: 1rem;
     border-bottom: .5px solid #777;
}

.logo-box {
     float: left;
}

.logo {
     color: #353353;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: 700;
     font-size: 4rem;
     letter-spacing: .4rem;
     margin-left: 5rem;
}

nav {
     padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar {
     float: right;
     list-style: none;
     margin-right: 10rem;
     margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.navbar li {
     display: inline-block;
}

.navbar li a {
     margin: 0 1rem;
     padding: .2rem .6rem;
     color: black;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
     transition: all .3s;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
     border-bottom: 2px solid #F9F871;
     transition: all .3s;
}

/* The sticky navbar */

.sticky {
     position: fixed;
     background-color: #353353;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
}

.sticky .navbar-lists {
     color: #fff;
}

.sticky .logo {
     color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

     <!-- Rubik fonts link -->
     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

     <!-- CSS links -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

     <title>Arun Bohra - Design Business Solutions</title>
</head>
<body>

     <header>
          <div class="hero-text-box u-text-align-center u-inline-block">
               <h1>Hello my name is Arun</h1>
               <h2 class="header-heading u-margin-top-small">I'm a front-end developer</h2>
               <a href="#" class="btn u-margin-top-small u-inline-block">Who am I</a>
          </div>
     </header>

     <div class="navigation">
          <nav class="clearfix">
               <div class="logo-box">
                    <a href="#" class="logo">
                         Arun
                    </a>
               </div>

               <ul class="navbar">
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">About me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">Skills</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>
          </nav>
     </div>

     <section class="about-section">
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>

     </section>

     <script src="js/index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

I want to add some smoothness when the navbar becomes sticky at the top. It would be great if I am able to do it with the transition property in css. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `transition: background duration;` property to navigation class. It will smooth out the background change.

```js
// jshint esversion: 6
window.onscroll = function() { myFunction(); };

let navbar = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation")[0];
let sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
       navbar.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
       navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
/* ------------------------------------- */
/* BASIC RESET */
/* ------------------------------------- */
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

html { font-size: 62.5%; }

body {
     box-sizing: inherit;
     color: #777;
     background-color: #fff;
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     font-size: 1.8rem;
     font-weight: 400;
     line-height: 1.5;
}

.clearfix {zoom: 1;}
.clearfix:after {
    content: '.';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE REUSABLE CONTENT */
/* ------------------------------------- */

/* HTML contents */

h1, h2.header-heading, h2 {
     margin: 0;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 {
     font-size: 4.5rem;
     color: #fff;
     letter-spacing: .4rem;
     word-spacing: .5rem;
     font-weight: 300;
}

h2 {
     font-size: 3.5rem;
}

/* Links */

a {
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline-block;
}

/* Buttons */

.btn {
     border: 1px solid #fff;
     border-radius: .3rem;
     font-size: 1.6rem;
     padding: 1.2rem 3.5rem;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     color: #fff;
     background-color: transparent;
     font-weight: bold;
     letter-spacing: .3rem;
     transition: all .2s;
}

.btn:hover {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #000;
}

/* Utility classes */

.u-margin-top-small {
     margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.u-text-align-center {
     text-align: center;
}

.u-inline-block {
     display: inline-block;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE HEADER SECTION */
/* ------------------------------------- */

header {
     background-color: #353353;
     height: 98vh;
}

.hero-text-box {
     position: absolute;
     top: 40%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h2.header-heading {
     font-size: 3.5rem;
     margin-top: 2rem;
     color: #F9F871;
     font-weight: 400;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE NAVBAR */
/* ------------------------------------- */

.navigation {
     position: relative;
     padding: 1rem;
     border-bottom: .5px solid #777;
     transition: background 0.5s;
}

.logo-box {
     float: left;
}

.logo {
     color: #353353;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: 700;
     font-size: 4rem;
     letter-spacing: .4rem;
     margin-left: 5rem;
}

nav {
     padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar {
     float: right;
     list-style: none;
     margin-right: 10rem;
     margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.navbar li {
     display: inline-block;
}

.navbar li a {
     margin: 0 1rem;
     padding: .2rem .6rem;
     color: black;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
     transition: all .3s;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
     border-bottom: 2px solid #F9F871;
     transition: all .3s;
}

/* The sticky navbar */

.sticky {
     position: fixed;
     background-color: #353353;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
}

.sticky .navbar-lists {
     color: #fff;
}

.sticky .logo {
     color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

     <!-- Rubik fonts link -->
     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

     <!-- CSS links -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

     <title>Arun Bohra - Design Business Solutions</title>
</head>
<body>

     <header>
          <div class="hero-text-box u-text-align-center u-inline-block">
               <h1>Hello my name is Arun</h1>
               <h2 class="header-heading u-margin-top-small">I'm a front-end developer</h2>
               <a href="#" class="btn u-margin-top-small u-inline-block">Who am I</a>
          </div>
     </header>

     <div class="navigation">
          <nav class="clearfix">
               <div class="logo-box">
                    <a href="#" class="logo">
                         Arun
                    </a>
               </div>

               <ul class="navbar">
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">About me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">Skills</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>
          </nav>
     </div>

     <section class="about-section">
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>

     </section>

     <script src="js/index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm guessing that whatever the case, we always have to apply transition property to the parent element. Is it correct?

Comment: Not necessary. The transition property is applied here to parent element, because its color changes, as you scroll down. So, basically, it applied to the element, whose properties are changing or to one that you want to animate.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you work with `max-height` and the desired `transition` at your navba, check it out:

```js
// jshint esversion: 6
window.onscroll = function() { myFunction(); };

let navbar = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation")[0];
let sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
       navbar.classList.add("sticky");

       // add the ready class after a tiny delay
       setTimeout(() => {
           navbar.classList.add("ready");
       }, 100);
  } else {
       navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
       
       // don't forget to also remove ready class
       navbar.classList.remove("ready");
  }
}
```

```css
/* ------------------------------------- */
/* BASIC RESET */
/* ------------------------------------- */
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

html { font-size: 62.5%; }

body {
     box-sizing: inherit;
     color: #777;
     background-color: #fff;
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     font-size: 1.8rem;
     font-weight: 400;
     line-height: 1.5;
}

.clearfix {zoom: 1;}
.clearfix:after {
    content: '.';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE REUSABLE CONTENT */
/* ------------------------------------- */

/* HTML contents */

h1, h2.header-heading, h2 {
     margin: 0;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 {
     font-size: 4.5rem;
     color: #fff;
     letter-spacing: .4rem;
     word-spacing: .5rem;
     font-weight: 300;
}

h2 {
     font-size: 3.5rem;
}

/* Links */

a {
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline-block;
}

/* Buttons */

.btn {
     border: 1px solid #fff;
     border-radius: .3rem;
     font-size: 1.6rem;
     padding: 1.2rem 3.5rem;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     color: #fff;
     background-color: transparent;
     font-weight: bold;
     letter-spacing: .3rem;
     transition: all .2s;
}

.btn:hover {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #000;
}

/* Utility classes */

.u-margin-top-small {
     margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.u-text-align-center {
     text-align: center;
}

.u-inline-block {
     display: inline-block;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE HEADER SECTION */
/* ------------------------------------- */

header {
     background-color: #353353;
     height: 98vh;
}

.hero-text-box {
     position: absolute;
     top: 40%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h2.header-heading {
     font-size: 3.5rem;
     margin-top: 2rem;
     color: #F9F871;
     font-weight: 400;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE NAVBAR */
/* ------------------------------------- */

.navigation {
     position: relative;
     padding: 1rem;
     border-bottom: .5px solid #777;
}

.logo-box {
     float: left;
}

.logo {
     color: #353353;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: 700;
     font-size: 4rem;
     letter-spacing: .4rem;
     margin-left: 5rem;
}

nav {
     padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar {
     float: right;
     list-style: none;
     margin-right: 10rem;
     margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.navbar li {
     display: inline-block;
}

.navbar li a {
     margin: 0 1rem;
     padding: .2rem .6rem;
     color: black;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
     transition: all .3s;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
     border-bottom: 2px solid #F9F871;
     transition: all .3s;
}

/* The sticky navbar */

.sticky {
     position: fixed;
     background-color: #353353;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
     max-height: 0px; /* set max-height as 0 */
     transition: height 1500ms linear; /* define your max-height transition */
}
.sticky.ready {
     max-height: 9999px; /* when "ready" the sticky navbar transitions to have a height */
}

.sticky .navbar-lists {
     color: #fff;
}

.sticky .logo {
     color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

     <!-- Rubik fonts link -->
     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

     <!-- CSS links -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

     <title>Arun Bohra - Design Business Solutions</title>
</head>
<body>

     <header>
          <div class="hero-text-box u-text-align-center u-inline-block">
               <h1>Hello my name is Arun</h1>
               <h2 class="header-heading u-margin-top-small">I'm a front-end developer</h2>
               <a href="#" class="btn u-margin-top-small u-inline-block">Who am I</a>
          </div>
     </header>

     <div class="navigation">
          <nav class="clearfix">
               <div class="logo-box">
                    <a href="#" class="logo">
                         Arun
                    </a>
               </div>

               <ul class="navbar">
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">About me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">Skills</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>
          </nav>
     </div>

     <section class="about-section">
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>

     </section>

     <script src="js/index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

You can fine adjust the `setTimeout` delay and the `transition durantion` to getter a better/smoother effect.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some code using flexbox and transitions on header and nav to improve the transition effect.

```js
// jshint esversion: 6
window.onscroll = function() { myFunction(); };

let navbar = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation")[0];
let sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
       navbar.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
       navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
/* ------------------------------------- */
/* BASIC RESET */
/* ------------------------------------- */
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

html { font-size: 62.5%; }

body {
     box-sizing: inherit;
     color: #777;
     background-color: #fff;
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     font-size: 1.8rem;
     font-weight: 400;
     line-height: 1.5;
}

.clearfix {zoom: 1;}
.clearfix:after {
    content: '.';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE REUSABLE CONTENT */
/* ------------------------------------- */

/* HTML contents */

h1, h2.header-heading, h2 {
     margin: 0;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 {
     font-size: 4.5rem;
     color: #fff;
     letter-spacing: .4rem;
     word-spacing: .5rem;
     font-weight: 300;
}

h2 {
     font-size: 3.5rem;
}

/* Links */

a {
     text-decoration: none;
     display: inline-block;
}

/* Buttons */

.btn {
     border: 1px solid #fff;
     border-radius: .3rem;
     font-size: 1.6rem;
     padding: 1.2rem 3.5rem;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     color: #fff;
     background-color: transparent;
     font-weight: bold;
     letter-spacing: .3rem;
     transition: all .2s;
}

.btn:hover {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #000;
}

/* Utility classes */

.u-margin-top-small {
     margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.u-text-align-center {
     text-align: center;
}

.u-inline-block {
     display: inline-block;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE HEADER SECTION */
/* ------------------------------------- */

header {
     background-color: #353353;
     height: 98vh;
}

.hero-text-box {
     position: absolute;
     top: 40%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h2.header-heading {
     font-size: 3.5rem;
     margin-top: 2rem;
     color: #F9F871;
     font-weight: 400;
}

/* ------------------------------------- */
/* THE NAVBAR */
/* ------------------------------------- */

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: .5px solid #777;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 80px;
  transition: all .5s;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.logo-box {
     float: left;
}

.logo {
     color: #353353;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: 700;
     font-size: 4rem;
     letter-spacing: .4rem;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.navbar {
     float: right;
     list-style: none;
}

.navbar li {
     display: inline-block;
}

.navbar li a {
     margin: 0 1rem;
     padding: .2rem .6rem;
     color: black;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
     transition: all .3s;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
     border-bottom: 2px solid #F9F871;
     transition: all .3s;
}

/* The sticky navbar */

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #353353;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
}

.sticky .navbar-lists {
     color: #fff;
}

.sticky .logo {
     color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

     <!-- Rubik fonts link -->
     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

     <!-- CSS links -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

     <title>Arun Bohra - Design Business Solutions</title>
</head>
<body>

     <header>
          <div class="hero-text-box u-text-align-center u-inline-block">
               <h1>Hello my name is Arun</h1>
               <h2 class="header-heading u-margin-top-small">I'm a front-end developer</h2>
               <a href="#" class="btn u-margin-top-small u-inline-block">Who am I</a>
          </div>
     </header>

     <div class="navigation">
          <nav class="clearfix">
               <div class="logo-box">
                    <a href="#" class="logo">
                         Arun
                    </a>
               </div>

               <ul class="navbar">
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">About me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">Skills</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-lists">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>
          </nav>
     </div>

     <section class="about-section">
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>
          <h2>Who am I</h2>

     </section>

     <script src="js/index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>


</html>
```